# Summation of series

Tags: summation

If the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{2011} \frac{n+2}{n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!}$$ can be written as $$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{a!}$$find the last three digits of a.

I have reduced the given expression to $$\frac{1}{(n+2)(n)!}$$ and I think I will have to use the method of differences but I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $n$ in your expression $$\frac{1}{(n+2)(n)!}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\frac1{(n+k)!}-\frac1{(n+k+1)!}=\frac{n+k}{(n+k+1)!}=\frac1{(n+k+1)(n+k-1)!}\ .$$

Comment: I understand this result but can you please tell me how you arrived at it? Also, I am having trouble applying this result to my expression

Comment: If, as stated in the answer, the sum is $\frac12-\frac1{a!}$, then your expression pretty much has to be something like my LHS.  Then all you have to do is find the value of $k$ to match your expression.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{2011} \frac{n+2}{n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{2011}\frac{1}{(n+2)(n)!} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{2011}\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{2011}\frac 1{(n+1)!}-\frac 1{(n+2)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{2011}\frac 1{(n+1)!}-\sum_{n=1}^{2012}\frac 1{(n+1)!}\\
&=\frac 1{(0+1)!}-\frac 1{(2012+1)!}\\
&=1-\frac 1{2013!}
\end{align}$$

NB - if the sum is taken from $n=1$ instead of $n=0$, then the result becomes
$$\frac 12-\frac 1{2013!}$$
which is in the form required, with the last three digits of $a$ being $013$.